# How to add a flag to my python code for telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to have a flag that will change the answer of my bot. Here is my code:

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
pills_adding_state = False

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi. I will help you remember all the medicine you need to take. Type add to add a medicine to your list")

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
def handle_list_of_pills_message(message):
    
    if message.text == "/add":
        pills_adding_state = True
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Type the medicine name")
    elif pills_adding_state ==True:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"medicine {} added".format(message.text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

I edited my code snippet a bit to make it a bit clearer. The goal is: user types "/add" and then they can type the name of the medicine as soon as the flag pills_adding_state is now true. But the code doesn't work as intended.

Unfortunately, changing the variable "pills_adding_state" doesn't affect the behavior of my bot. What do I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: can you clarify your question? What do you want the code to do?

Comment: I edited my question a bit. maybe now it's a bit clearer

Comment: you still didn't include what you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question once more)

Comment: The goal is: user types "/add" and then they can type the name of the medicine as soon as the flag pills_adding_state is now true. But the code doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's a very BAD way to do it,P lease don't globals like that!, that would mean, you can type /add and someone can type the medicine name, or two people can type /add one after another and hell will lose, ITS BAD.
2. You should be using the global tag to reference a global (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)).
3. You never set `pills_adding_state` to `False`, so Your command will be a one time use.
4. `elif pills_adding_state ==True:` is redundant, since well `pills_adding_state` is `True`, the if block will run, `elif pills_adding_state:` does the job well.